# Getting error when attempting to Load Picasso library

Tags: android, picasso

This is my code:
`Picasso.get().load(kl.getImage()).Into(userprofileImage);` .

I added the Picasso library but `Load` also gives an error like `'load (java.lang.String)'`

This is my gradle code implementation `'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`

Comment: The main SO site is English-only (not sure if there's a Turkish (?) one.

Comment: please share your gradle dependency as well. and also translate your question to English. (I know Turkish but many poepl on this website don't, naturally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version is the following, try this:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

And then it is also a good idea to clean the project and then rebuild.

Comment: There's also 2.8 which is newer, even if the semantic versioning is broken.